# Nginx 4th level domain wildcard redirect

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm currently serving `https` on second and third level of my domain (**wildcard**) and also redirect all `http` traffic to `https` for these. Now I would like to serve 4th level subdomains with with `http` **only**, since I can't get certificates for any domains in the form of `*.*.example.com`

```
# Now
example.com -> https: 
*.example.com -> https:
# What I want
*.*.example.com -> http:
```

I tried with the following config, but it still redirected to https on *.*.example.com :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    include /etc/nginx/headers.conf;
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

    access_log off;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name *.*.example.com;
    include /etc/nginx/headers.conf;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8087/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        access_log off;
}

server {
        server_name example.com *.example.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /key.pem;
        include /etc/nginx/headers.conf;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8087/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        access_log off;
}
```

Edit: precedence isn't relevant. PCRE are working.

Comment: what's `didn't work`? please add nginx error_log entries and/or startup errors if it happened. anyway, [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)s can only have **an** asterisk only on the name's start or end, and only on a dot border. try using regex, something like `"~^.+\..+\.foobar\.com%"` should suffice.

Comment: Also, you need to consider the order of precedence. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Comment: rixhard is right place your *. *. dom on thw first place

Comment: @mrforsetti was right. Although the regex wasn't completely working. You have to exclude the `.` too.  I went with `~^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.example\.com$` and `~^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.example\.com$` and walked right into the next problem.